# jenkins integration with bitbucket webhook

Tags: jenkins, build, triggers, bitbucket, webhooks

i created a pipeline job in jenkins with "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket"
[image]

then i created a webhook on bitbucket

[image]

but everytime when i push jenkins don't trigger the build

[image]

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request cannot be executed; I/O reactor status: STOPPED
 when i open my webhook i see this error

Comment: What's your Jenkins' version?

Comment: my jenkins version is 2.224

Comment: it was access permission problem it's okay now thank you